# How to exclude styles for a some specific elements using css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div id="header" class="top-bar">
...
</div>

<div id="specificdiv" class="top-bar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <li class="dropdown active">
            <li class="dropdown active">
            <li class="dropdown active">
        <li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="top-bar">
...
</div>
```

I need to exclude style for specific `<li>` tags under `div id="specificdiv"`.
I could exclude first element using this

```
.top-bar li:not(:first-of-type) {
    float: none;
}
```

but how to remove rest 2 as well?

Comment: so you want to add style to all `li` under `top-bar`? isnt that a bad idea to create nested `li`?

Comment: Why do you have `li` elements nested directly within a `li`?

Comment: it's not nested. I made some changes in .top-bar li style & that's y it is messed up when i checked it with firebug... so i need to exclude this style from .top-bar .li

Comment: I know that technically it's valid markup, but that just results in all the items sharing the same `ul` parent. I was commenting based on the peculiar indentation for your `li.dropdown.active` elements which seems to imply that they're supposed to be nested in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the direct descendant selector `>`. It only selects the immediate descendants of the targeted parents.

You could use `#specificdiv ul > li` and it will only select li on the first level of children.

And as BoltClock pointed out, you should wrap the `li` whose parent is a `li` inside of a `ul`.

```
<div id="specificdiv" class="top-bar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown active">
        <li class="dropdown active">
        <li class="dropdown active">
      </ul>
    <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you need **nth-child(an+b)** you can use it like this

```
li:nth-child(2){
  ..
}
li:nth-child(3){
  ..
}
```

now you hve a lot of alternative

```
ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {  
  color: #ccc;
}



li:nth-child(4n-7) {  /* or 4n+1 */
    color: green;   
}
```

and if you want to check special lis use the **>**  like this

```
div#pecificdiv ul.myList >li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;   
}
```

check this link  for useful nth-child recipes

http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

and this

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add class for the `<li>`, that you want to style? 
Example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="someClass">
        <li class="dropdown active">
        <li class="dropdown active">
        <li class="dropdown active">
    <li>
</ul>
```

And then your style:

```
.someClass{
     float:none;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry... li is not nested under li ...it's actually something like Cody Guldner has mentioned ... mine had typo error...

Answer (score 0):

```
#specificdiv li:not(:first-of-type) 
{
     float: none;
}
```

it will work.

# is used to select element by id. example #my will select element which has id=my

Comment: but this is excluding only first element.

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to do.to which element apply the style.